# Can we include both JSON payload and CSV File using form-data in POSTMAN?

Tags: python, api, flask, postman, postman-collection-runner

I am trying to send a **POST** request to my `Python Flask Server`. I tried to send a **CSV** file using the `form-data` option of **POSTMAN**. It was successfully received by the Flask server.

Now, I want to send a **JSON** payload along with the **CSV** file which will consist of the `User credentials`.

I tried the below method but it does not seem to be working. Although, I am receiving the **CSV** file but the **JSON** is still not received by the `Flask server`.

[image: POSTMAN Screenshot]

```
class Upload_File(Resource):

    def post(self):

        file_ = request.files['file']
        Q_data = pd.read_csv(file_, header=None, names=['Questions'])
        print(Q_data)      # successfully displays file content
        data = request.get_json(force=True)   # gives None
```

#### EDIT

The issue was with the `Flask` code. The working code is -

```
class Upload_File(Resource):

    def post(self):

        file_ = request.files['file']
        Q_data = pd.read_csv(file_, header=None, names=['Questions'])
        print(Q_data)      # successfully displays file content
        username = request.form.get('username') # modified
        password = request.form.get('password') # modified
```

Comment: If it is user credentials, it is better to use something like `headers`

Comment: I wish to send any type of `JSON` object, not necessarily `credentials`. It can also be an `insensitive data`.

Answer (score 0):

The request is parsed as Form data. So, you need to check whether you can get it via `request.post` dictionary.

Example:

```
class Upload_File(Resource):

    def post(self):

        file_ = request.files['file']
        Q_data = pd.read_csv(file_, header=None, names=['Questions'])
        print(Q_data)      # successfully displays file content
        data = request.post['admin']
```

Comment: The issue is with the `Flask` part and not `POSTMAN`. Thankyou for making me think the other way. I tried some modifications. I replaced `data` with `username = request.form.get('username')` and similarly for `password`.